# HTML to PDF issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf-generation

Background - ASP .Net site with user authentication. Page is a regular HTML with gridview, panels, textboxes, labels, tables etc

I am trying to get the current web page the user is viewing into a PDF using the free iText dll.

I have the below code which i thought would have done the trick:

```
Dim myRequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(Request.Url)

myRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("administrator", "password")
myRequest.Method = "GET"

Dim myResponse As WebResponse = myRequest.GetResponse
Dim sr As New StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
Dim result As String = sr.ReadToEnd
sr.Close()

myResponse.Close()
HTMLToPDF(result) ' "This line sends the HTML to be converted into a PDF"
```

Unfortunately this shows the login page with some text (the text is //if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to
load.'); //
.style1 { width: 100%; } .style2 { width: 334px; } .style3 { width: 303px; })

Since the site is using authentication i think whats happening is when the request is made it needs the username and password but as you can see from the above code i am sending in the username and password to see if it would work but its not.

Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this or other workarounds?

Comment: Reading *Ajax* in that text makes me assume that the page essentially is generated on the client side using JavaScript. Your `HTMLToPDF` call, on the other hand, seems to expect ready built html as input, not merely some JavaScript.

Comment: Ok - that error has now gone but i still cant get past the authentication bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for anyone that would like to know..... I had deny all users set in my config file which was causing the problem. Adjusting to allow admins resolved this.